# How do I write an unimplemented function that returns impl Trait without dummy code?

Tags: rust

I tried this:

```
trait T {}

fn f() -> impl T {
    unimplemented!();
}

fn main() {
    f();
}
```

But it gives this error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `!: T` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:3:11
  |
3 | fn f() -> impl T {
  |           ^^^^^^ the trait `T` is not implemented for `!`
  |
  = note: the return type of a function must have a statically known size
```

This compiles if a branch in `f` returns something:

```
struct S {}

trait T {}

impl T for S {}

fn f(a: u32) -> impl T {
    if a == 0 {
        panic!();
    } else {
        S {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    f(5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/36375).

The easy (cheating) answer is to implement your trait for `!`:

```
impl T for ! {}
```

You can see in the [tracking issue for promoting `!` to a type](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/35121) that much discussion has been around which traits to implement for a type.

There was also [an RFC to implement traits automatically for `!`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1637), but it was not accepted. This requires "implementing" any methods in the trait because [another proposed RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1699) was also postponed:

```
trait T {
    fn hello(&self) -> u32;
}

impl T for ! {
    fn hello(&self) -> u32 {
        *self
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this require providing dummy implementations of T's members for `!`?